# decode dean edwards javascript packer with a php class

Tags: php, javascript, decode

Class file http://pastebin.com/apGPiAXd

I found a php port that encodes and decodes the dean edwards packer for javascript. Located here [`http://joliclic.free.fr/php/javascript-packer/en/`](http://joliclic.free.fr/php/javascript-packer/en/). I am not interested in the encoding aspect of this class, but the decoding part. I would like to take something like this

`eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('4.8=9(a){1 b=e f();1 c=4.g("*");5(1 i=0;i<c.6;i++){2(c[i].3.h(" ")>=0){1 d=c[i].3.k(" ");5(1 j=0;j<d.6;j++){2(d[j]==a){b.7(c[i])}}}l 2(c[i].3==a){b.7(c[i])}}m b}',23,23,'|var|if|className|document|for|length|push|getElementsByClassName|function|||||new|Array|getElementsByTagName|indexOf|||split|else|return'.split('|'),0,{}))`

and place it in a variable and run it through the class to be decoded. I am not sure how to get the javascript into the class to be decoded? So maybe something like this:

```
require 'class.JavaScriptPacker.php';
$packed_javascript = $_GET["js"];

/* run $packed_javascript through class*/

return $decoded_javascript;
```

Comment: Have you tried? I mean what did not work? Would be good to know, if the class has a decode function it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @hakre i dont know how to test anything because i dont know how to run packed javascript through the class to get it decoded

Comment: Just seeing, that PHP class does not have a decode function. This would need a decode function.

Comment: @hakre in the class file its called $fastdecode line 43 - http://pastebin.com/apGPiAXd

Comment: That property is related to the javascript decoding in the browser, that's now what you're looking for. You need a PHP decode functionality, not to change the type of javascript decoder.

Comment: @hakre oh darn ok well i appreciate you taking the time to look over my post

Answer (score 1):

You can simple open up a **developer console in your browser** (ctrl+j in chrome, or firebug etc), paste your packed JS code into the console and before you hit enter, **simply replace "eval" with "console.log" or "alert"**.

I know this post is old but I just had the same problem and thought I'd post my solution. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

here is unpacked java script of above . is that u want??

```
document.getElementsByClassName=function(a)
    {
    var b=new Array();
    var c=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0;
    i<c.length;
    i++)
        {
        if(c[i].className.indexOf(" ")>=0)
            {
            var d=c[i].className.split(" ");
            for(var j=0;
            j<d.length;
            j++)
                {
                if(d[j]==a)
                    {
                    b.push(c[i])
                }
            }
        }
        else if(c[i].className==a)
            {
            b.push(c[i])
        }
    }
    return b
}
```

[Reference](http://matthewfl.com/unPacker.html)

Comment: thank you, but I want to be able to send packed javascript as a string to the class to be decoded and shown back to me. I cant rely on a 3rd party website

Comment: there are a lots of open source project which u can download and use personally.

Comment: @diEcho: Acutally this looks like -1: You have just used a third party website to decode some javascript and pasted it in here - but not answered the question at all. I wonder if you can really provide a PHP class that can decode packed javascript instead of making words.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but here is simple decode writen in php

```
<?php

$a = "eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('4.8=9(a){1 b=e f();1 c=4.g("*");5(1 i=0;i<c.6;i++){2(c[i].3.h(" ")>=0){1 d=c[i].3.k(" ");5(1 j=0;j<d.6;j++){2(d[j]==a){b.7(c[i])}}}l 2(c[i].3==a){b.7(c[i])}}m b}',23,23,'|var|if|className|document|for|length|push|getElementsByClassName|function|||||new|Array|getElementsByTagName|indexOf|||split|else|return'.split('|'),0,{}))";

$pos = strpos($a, '}(');
$a = substr($a, $pos);
$pos = strpos($a, ",'");
$b = substr($a, 0, $pos);
$c = substr($a, $pos+2);
$pos = strpos($c, "'.");
$c = substr($c, 0, $pos);

$items = explode('|', $c);

//var_dump($items);

for ($i = count($items); $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $b = str_replace($i, $items[$i], $b);
}

$b = str_replace("\'", "'", $b);

echo ' procedure: ';
echo $b;

?>
```